# SQL : Select 20 entries from a specific id

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select 20 entries in my "USERS" table from a specific id numbers.

```
=========================
====== USERS ============
=========================
- id
- name
- surname
- mail
- town
=========================
```

For example, i have 100 entries in USERS table, the id parameter passed in my script is 34.
I would like to retrieve the 20 next entries from entry which is 34.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE id >= 34
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 20
```